# rspec gets "undefined method `build_rb_world_factory' for nil"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I'm updating a Rails 3.2 app to Ruby 2.2.2. I've pulled the Rails version up to 3.2.22, which is necessary for Ruby 2.2.2. That went relatively well but prompted a Cucumber update, from 1.2.1 to 1.3.20. (I don't recall the details, because that was several failed efforts ago, but I think my features were passing but then exiting false before I did this.)

Now Cucumber features run fine (albeit with a ton of unrelated Ruby 2.2.2 warnings), but rspec does not. Specifically, when I run `rake spec` I get this error:

```
/path/to/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_dsl.rb:15:in `build_rb_world_factory': undefined method `build_rb_world_factory' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The stack trace leads through Capybara (2.4.4, pinned for other reasons), ActiveSupport, and Bundler back up to rspec-core.

All my searches trying to find similar issues just lead to the code, because it seems like the only place this method name exists is in code.

Why am I getting this error from Capybara/Cucumber when running rspec? How can I fix it?

ETA: Stack trace, with paths condensed a bit:

```
/path/to/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_dsl.rb:15:in `build_rb_world_factory': undefined method `build_rb_world_factory' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /path/to/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_dsl.rb:50:in `World'
    from /path/to/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /path/to/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /path/to/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /path/to/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /path/to/gems/capybara-screenshot-0.2.2/lib/capybara-screenshot.rb:96:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /path/to/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /path/to/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /path/to/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /path/to/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /path/to/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /path/to/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /path/to/app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /path/to/app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/app/spec/spec_helper.rb:10:in `require'
    from /path/to/app/spec/spec_helper.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/app/spec/controllers/academic_years_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /path/to/app/spec/controllers/academic_years_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
    from /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
    from /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
    from /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
/path/to/ruby/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -I/path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib:/path/to/gems/rspec-support-3.2.2/lib /path/to/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb failed
```

My hunch is that there's a configuration file which needs to be rebuilt somewhere.

Comment: a stacktrace for the error may help narrow it down, although the fact that cucumber is trying to initialize when you're running specs would tend to imply you have a require or 2 in the wrong place.

Comment: ok - so it looks like capybara/cucumber is getting required by capybara-screenshot even when you're not using cucumber.  Easiest solution would probably be to upgrade capybara-screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your stacktrace - the capybara-screenshot gem is requiring capybara/cucumber even though you're running specs which aren't using cucumber.  This means World is called from capybara/cucumber against a non-initialized cucumber, and gives the error.  The version of capybara-screenshot you're using is really old, and the code that required capybara/cucumber has since been removed so you should probably update the version of capybara-screenshot you're using, and add

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara-screenshot/cucumber'
```

to your env.rb or other cucumber support file

Comment: The `capybara-screenshot` gem update was sufficient to get rspec going again. I've added the `require` lines but it doesn't look like they were a blocker - at some level I'm wondering if capybara-screenshot is actually even in use. But that's a different problem entirely.

Comment: the require lines would be required for your cucumber tests, not the specs - hence why they should be in env.rb (or other cucumber support file)

Comment: ETA - yes, I added the `require` lines to the cucumber setup `env.rb`, but the features ran cleanly before I did that.

Comment: ok -- you must have them required through something else then too - no harm